# Recover Unsaved SQL Query Scripts in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

From where to recover unsaved SQL scripts in SQL server Management Studio?

I have checked in following path:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files`
```

But did not find any scripts.

Comment: Learn from your mistake; save scripts you mean to keep in the future.

Answer (score 0):

IF it doesn't pass 24 hours, you can use

```
Use <database>
SELECT 
  eq.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], 
  es.text AS [Script] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS eq
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(eq.sql_handle) AS es
ORDER BY eq.last_execution_time DESC
```

OR you can check following folders

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Comment: still not able to recover, any other way by which i can recover?